# Where are the DH parameters in a Server Exchange Message?

Tags: diffie-hellman, key-exchange

In a Server Key Exchange message, isn't it supposed to send both the public key's parameters which are for DH: the g(generator) and p(modulus), but the message only contains one public key called Pubkey: [image]so is that the g, p or both, or is there a fixed variable like there is for the RSA public exponent which is 2^16+1? And where is g^e mod p?

Comment: Note: using 2^16+1 for RSA public exponent is fairly common but by no means required. SSL/TLS used ephemeral RSA keys only for some of the deliberately-weak and long-obsolete 'export' ciphersuites, and in that case it explicitly sent m and e, see rfc2246 7.4.3. Mostly it uses static RSA keys in an X.509 certificate which are encoded as standardized for X.509/PKIX by rfc3279.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screenshot:

> ```
> EC Diffie-Hellman Server Params
> Curve Type: named_curve
> Named Curve: secp256r1
> Pubkey: ...
> Signature: ...
> ```

This tells us the following: You used a key exchange with [ECDHE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman). They key exchange used P-256 (the elliptic curve, aka secp256r1) and the given value describes the public ECDH key and the signature on this value.

The paramters you are looking for are hard-coded for P-256 and documented in several places (for example in [this PDF](http://www.secg.org/SEC2-Ver-1.0.pdf)). The $g^e\bmod p$ you're looking for is the Pubkey which is mentioned in the screenshot.

Comment: do you mean that this if it is a DH only key exchange, it will send the p, and g alone, but this is a ECDHE nstead?

Comment: @user3407319 Yes (?), if it were proper (plain) DH it would send $p$ and $g$ but as this is ECDHE it only sends "use this standard curve"